# HTML button that reloads refering page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a HTML error page which has a button with text Try Again. When the user clicks this button I would like to reload the refering page.

Looking on Google there are a few ways to do this, but I am unsure of which is the best way that will work in the majority of browsers.

Anyone help?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: @AJ Is this error generated for a broken link?  If so, I don't think you want to send the user back to the previous page to retry a broken link?  Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code that handled the original HTTP request resulting in the error knows that URL, so it should simply create a link back on the error page; just a simple link, or whatever else that's appropriate for your overall site design.

**Do not rely on the HTTP "REFERER" value.**

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload();" value="Try again" />
```

Comment: That reloads the current page, he wants to reload the referring page.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have a window location object that has a reload function

```
window.location.reload()
```

So you button will look like

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Comment: He wants to reload the referring page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the history api:

```
<a href="javascript-required" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;">Try again</a>
```